# Angular 6, shared module in individual lazyloaded modules causes app not to work on change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I have a strange issue which didn't was problem when I was using angular 5.

Here is the situation

In App routing module i have

```
{
    path: 'moduleA',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: './modules/moduleA.module#moduleA'
},
{
    path: 'moduleB',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: './modules/moduleB.module#moduleB'
},
```

Then I have a Shared module which has only one component for rating and it is declared and exported ..

```
import { NgModule,  ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RatingComponent } from './components/rating/rating.component';
import { RatingService } from './services/rating.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RatingComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        RatingComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        RatingService
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                RatingService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Shared module is imported in both modules... when I run ng serve --aot the app works well, but then when I change something in the code of Shared, ModuleA or ModuleB the CLI compiles successfully but in the browser I get error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
```

I have to stop the cli and runs it again and it works properly. Does anyone knows what might be the issue?

It happens only on version 6 (tried 6.0.7 and 6.1.0), while if I try this on version 5 it works without any issue. Also if I exclude the SharedModule from ModuleA or B then it will work good, but in that case the module isn't shared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some in depth analysis it turns out that even that application works with lazyload of the modules, in order to be able to work without the issue mentioned above, it turns out that in the app.module.ts file I have to import  all modules that I was loading with lazyload.